# Почему когда я меня цвет рамки QFrame, меняется цвет у всех других виджетов?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qss, qlabel, parent

Такая проблема, я меняю цвет рамки и меняется цвет у всех виджетов. 
Я знаю, что это можно исправить с помощью `setObjectName`, но мне интересно как это сделать без это.

Почему меняется цвет у всех виджетов?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QDialog, QLabel, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QApplication,
                             QHBoxLayout, QFrame)
import sys


class WindowIngredient(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WindowIngredient, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setModal(True)

        self.frame_for_window_product = QFrame()
        self.frame_for_window_product.setStyleSheet('''QFrame {
                                border: 2px solid #1f178f;
                                background-color: #ffffff;
        }''')

        self.name_product = QLabel()

        self.line = QFrame()
        self.line.setFrameShape(QFrame.HLine)

        self.line_weight = QLineEdit()
        self.btn = QPushButton('Добавить')

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.name_product)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.line)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.line_weight)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.frame_for_window_product.setLayout(self.vbox)

        self.main_box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_box.addWidget(self.frame_for_window_product)
        self.setLayout(self.main_box)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = WindowIngredient()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `self.frame_for_window_product` является родителем для ваших других виджетов.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QDialog, QLabel, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QApplication,
                             QHBoxLayout, QFrame)
import sys


class WindowIngredient(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WindowIngredient, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setModal(True)

        self.frame_for_window_product = QFrame()
        self.frame_for_window_product.setStyleSheet('''QFrame {
                                border: 2px solid #1f178f;
                                background-color: #ffffff;
        }''')

        self.name_product = QLabel('Hello World')

        self.line = QFrame()
        self.line.setFrameShape(QFrame.HLine)

        self.line_weight = QLineEdit()
        self.btn = QPushButton('Добавить')

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.name_product)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.line)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.line_weight)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.frame_for_window_product.setLayout(self.vbox)

        self.main_box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_box.addWidget(self.frame_for_window_product)
        self.setLayout(self.main_box)
# +++        
        self.frame_for_window_product.setObjectName('frame_for_window_product')
        print(f'parent self.name_product: {self.name_product.parent().objectName()}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = WindowIngredient()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Подскажите а как изменить родителя у Hello Word?

Вам не надо ничего изменять, прости задайте свои стили для `self.name_product`.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QDialog, QLabel, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QApplication,
                             QHBoxLayout, QFrame)
import sys


class WindowIngredient(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WindowIngredient, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setModal(True)

        self.frame_for_window_product = QFrame()
        self.frame_for_window_product.setStyleSheet('''QFrame {
                                border: 2px solid #1f178f;
                                background-color: #ffffff;
        }''')

        self.name_product = QLabel('Hello World')
# +++
        self.name_product.setStyleSheet('''QLabel {
                                border: 3px solid #ff178f;
                                background-color: #dff;
        }''')
        
        self.line = QFrame()
        self.line.setFrameShape(QFrame.HLine)

        self.line_weight = QLineEdit()
        self.btn = QPushButton('Добавить')

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.name_product)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.line)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.line_weight)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.frame_for_window_product.setLayout(self.vbox)

        self.main_box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_box.addWidget(self.frame_for_window_product)
        self.setLayout(self.main_box)
# +++        
        self.frame_for_window_product.setObjectName('frame_for_window_product')
        print(f'parent self.name_product: {self.name_product.parent().objectName()}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = WindowIngredient()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подскажите а как изменить родителя у Hello Word?

Comment: @Tesla я дополнил свой ответ, проверьте.